# What is the meaning of "it's just that" in this video?

Tags: meaning-in-context, spoken-english

https://youtu.be/T_MUer2ojV4

At 02:41
She says

> **It's just that** I'm an artist
>   this is not what I'm supposed to be doing

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't watch the film, but "it's just that ...." is often used to introduce the reason for some discontent, issue, trouble, or concern.    "It" refers to the situation that is the basis for the feeling.

> Why are you looking at me in that way?
>   --It's just that you are eating *my* sandwich.  That one with the cheese is yours.
>
> You seem unhappy here.
>   -- It's just that I love the outdoors. I shouldn't be working in an office.

Comment: Does it's just that mean because? Well if that so i don't think it will work in this example. Dogs don't actually like bones. It's just that they never get the meat :/

Comment: I'd say it's almost an interjection. In the video (and most examples that come to mind) the speaker is going on about something and then inserts this and then changes the direction of the conversation. Instead of because, I would say it is interchangeable with but. I think that the classic example of this would be, "Look, I really like you, you're a really great guy. You're so good to me. It's just that, I think we should see other people."